# Formating entry date like Twitter or Facebook

Tags: channel-entries, date, time, entry-date

Is there a way to format the date output so it reads like it does on Twitter or Facebook.

For example if a post was posted 2 days ago the output would be '2 days ago', the same goes for weeks, so if the entry was posted 2 weeks ago it says '2 weeks ago'.

I only need it to go up to 2 weeks, after that it will switch back to a normal date format.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least three plugins that can format dates like "x time-units ago."

- [Nice Time](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nic)
- [Time Ago](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/time-ago)
- [WB Relative Date](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wb-relative-date)

Since you only need display a relative date for the first two weeks from the entry date, you'll need to wrap your date in a conditional based on `{current_time}` and use a bit of math. Or as you pointed out in your comment, the Time Ago plugin has a `revert_to_date_format` parameter for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, Time Ago has a great solution with the revert_to_date_format option, i can just modify the add-on to make it work with 14 days

Comment: Ah, nice! Very useful option.

Answer (score 1):

There are several such add-ons listed on devot:ee. [Here's a search for "relative date."](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=relative%20date&addon_version_support=ee2)